# Enumerate different elements of a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm struggling to elaborate an Arrayformula to enumerate the different elements of a column, I have five different type of jobs and I have each job numerated independently. I've prepared a Spreadsheet with the elements in Column A and the desired result in orange

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IYlXY_HyO3lihs4NHilhPXPWyX_L86WRjGUEHQZtEpY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;Σ&" "&countif(A1:Σ;Σ))))
```

[image]

Comment: Really like your approach.  Since you are using an infinite range, you might consider wrapping it in `TOCOL(formula; 1)` which will constrain the results to 11 rows rather than `ROWS(F:F)`  Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative Solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(A1:A11&" "&(if(len(A1:A);(COUNTIFS(A1:A;A1:A;ROW(A1:A);"<="&ROW(A1:A)));));""))
```

##### Explanation:

Using the following formula, this will number each item on the list:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(A1:A);(COUNTIFS(A1:A;A1:A;ROW(A1:A);"<="&ROW(A1:A)));))
```

[image]
Then concatinating the actual word to itself leading to the final desired result.

#### Final Result:

[image]

##### Reference:

- [Make Duplicates to Unique by Assigning Extra Characters in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/make-duplicates-to-unique-in-google-sheets/#Step_2_Formulas_in_%E2%80%98Test_1%E2%80%99_Tab_Populating_Sequential_Roman_Alphabets_Numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in B1:

```
=arrayformula(A1:A11&" "&countifs(A1:A11;A1:A11;row(A1:A11);"<="&row(A1:A11)))
```